# R How to loop multiple calculations over each unique factors in a column of my data and append each calculation to a new column or table

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration, purrr

I have a big set of data, and I wish to make a report for each of the company in my dataset. The report will have 4 columns, the first 3 columns will be fixed texts, and the last column requires calculation based on each company's data. The ideal out put will be like this:

```
Issue_code    Description   Issue   # of violations  
   ..            ..          ..           2
   ..            ..          ..           5
   ..            ..          ..           18
```

And there is about 16 unique companies in the data. Therefore, at the end I shall have 16 tables like this with identical first 3 columns and different last column.

My initiation of the loop is following:

```
for (i in unique(data$company) {

  i1 <-  filter(company == i) %>%
         summarise_at("ID", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

  i2 <-  filter(company == i) %>%
         filter(Frequency > 5) %>%
         count()

  i3 <-  filter(company == i) %>%
         filter( Year %in% c(1998, 1996, 1997) %>%
         summarise_at("amount", funs(sum(is.na(.))))
}
```

And I have trouble assigning(looping) these calculations to corresponding tables or columns. I was thinking making a list of 16 columns of "# of violations" and assign each calculation to each table, but my R skills couldn't reach as far as my thoughts. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We can do a group by company and use multiple columns in `summarise_at`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(company) %>%
      summarise_at(vars(ID,Frequency, Date), funs(sum(is.na(.)))
```

---

If we are interested in applying different functions to the columns, then use `map`

```
map2(c("ID", "Frequency", "Date"), listofFunctions, ~ 
                data %>%
                    group_by(company) %>%
                    summarise_at(.x, funs(.y))
```

Comment: My apologies, I didn't specify that not all the calculations are counting NA's, and also some calculations require a further filter. I will edit my code in the question. Thank you akrun!